# How To find a WebSocket from a REST bean

Tags: rest, jboss, websocket

I have a javascript client that connects to a server via websockets and sends data via ajax to a server.
Once the server finished processing the data, I want to send a message via the websocket to the client.
Problem is: How do I find the WebSocket from the REST bean (hopefully in the same session...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Websocket connection starts with a HTTP handshake. On the handshake you also receive cookies (e.g. the session ID cookie) so you get access to the HTTP session.

[From the JSR 356 Java API for WebSocket spec:](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=356)

> Because websocket connections are initiated with an http request, there is an association between the HttpSession under which a client is operating and any websockets that are established within that HttpSession. The API allows access in the opening handshake to the unique HttpSession corresponding to that same client.

That's the point to associate a HTTP session with a websocket connection in whatever way you find fit.

Comment: But it seems it is not supported for @SessionScope - I'll implement it myself :-) thanks!